Different behaviour of recursion-based powerset in C and Python
On trying to implement a recursion-based technique to find powerset of a list, there was different behaviour in the C and Python implementation.
It was first tried in Python using pseudocode as follows
def(f, n):
  if n<N:
    f(s+[n+1], n+1)
    f(s, n+1)

  if n==N:
    # all elements end up here

f([], 1)

This calls the sets up to N, starting from 2 by adding another element and not adding in another.
My c code is as follows
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define u8 uint8_t


#define N 4
void f(bool *s, u8 n){


  printf("%*s", 4*n, "");
  printf("[");
  for(int i=2;i<=N;i++)
    if(s[i]) printf("%d ", i);
  printf("]\n");



  if(n<N){
    f(s, n+1);
    s[n+1] = true;
    f(s, n+1);
  }

  if(n==N){}

}

int main(){
  bool s[N+1] = {false};
  f(s, 1);
}

To avoid using a dynamic list, I've used a boolean array. The problematic code is probably the if block with n<N check. This code uses tabs to space between different levels of recursion to make debugging easier.
The same for Python
N = 4
def f(s, n):
    print('\t'*n, s)
    if n<N:
        f(s+[n+1], n+1)
        f(s, n+1)
    if(n==N):
        pass
            

f([], 1)

C output
 []
        []
            []
                []
                [4 ]
            [3 4 ]
                [3 4 ]
                [3 4 ]
        [2 3 4 ]
            [2 3 4 ]
                [2 3 4 ]
                [2 3 4 ]
            [2 3 4 ]
                [2 3 4 ]
                [2 3 4 ]

Python output
     []
         [2]
             [2, 3]
                 [2, 3, 4]
                 [2, 3]
             [2]
                 [2, 4]
                 [2]
         []
             [3]
                 [3, 4]
                 [3]
             []
                 [4]
                 []


In the Python function you have f(s.append(n+1), n+1) which is equivalent to s.append(n+1); f(s, n+1). In the C code you have f(s, n+1); s[n+1] = true; which is not equivalent.

yes, sorry, I wrote it before I changed to s+[..], before .append changes the object and doesn't return it(or returns None)

@Someprogrammerdude, I don't get it, there was no way to change a copied version of array with one thing changed, so I just change the value and pass it(since c takes care of the copy by itself)

C doesn't "takes care of the copy" b/c it doesn't make a copy.

It's still an ordering problem I feel. f(s+[n+1], n+1) is essentially temp = s+[n+1]; f(temp, n+1). You append before the recursive call, while the C code does the append after. But there's also another problem: s+[n+1] will create a new list, which is passed to the recursive call. In C you can't create a new "list" (or array), all function calls will share the single array.

The difference is in these pieces of code:
Python:
    f(s + [n+1], n+1)
    f(s, n+1)

C:
    f(s, n+1);
    s[n+1] = true;
    f(s, n+1);

The issues:

The C code makes the selection in a different order, including n+1 for the second recursive call -- while the Python version does that for the first recursive call. This is not really a problem, but partly explains the difference in output.

More of a problem is that the C code does not set s[n+1] back to false after the second recursive call, which will (badly) impact the behaviour higher up the recursion tree. This is a bug that is not present in the Python code, where the selection of i+1 only exists during the recursive call, but doesn't continue to be selected after that recursive call has finished.


To fix the bug you could add the following statement after the second recursive call:
    s[n+1] = false;

But to make the output the same as for the Python code, also switch the order:
    s[n+1] = true;
    f(s, n+1);
    s[n+1] = false;
    f(s, n+1);


Can you elaborate a bit more on how exactly it impacts? If I understand correctly, after first call, a copy of the array is given to it and modified s to second. In the sense of giving they receive exactly the same "information", so what does adding s[n+1] = false change?

It will not give a change right there at the spot, but later on. In your print loop you will visit also items with indices of s that were set at some deeper recursion depth via a sibling branch in the recursion tree. If you haven't reset those entries back to false before returning from deeper recursions, then this print loop will still see them as set to true, which is not what you want.
